# Shade Smooth vs. edges

Tags: modeling, shaders

Here is a strange thing:
it's a polyhedron and it's shade is flat:

[image]

i want to smoothen it's faces, so i use "Shade Smooth":

[image]

weird things happend with edges - no good.
Than i separate polyhedron's faces:

[image]

and here it is - result that i want. Than i join back polyhedron's faces:

[image]

and it's edges don't retein their previous "weird" state, they stay the way that i want them to be.

Why is it happens, and is there a shorter way to get result that i want?

Comment: Use `smooth shading` and turn on `Object Data Properties/Normals/auto smooth` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By splitting and re-joining the faces, you're creating *double edges*.
That improves shading on sharp edges (since the edges are no longer continuous).

You can achieve the same by adding the *Edge Split Modifier*.

[image]

Or by selecting all vertices and using *Edge > Split*

[image]